# RODBC - MSSQL response - character problems

Tags: sql-server, r, character-encoding, rodbc

I'm trying to query a table of my MS SQL Server from R and work with the data. Somewhere along the way some of my characters are apparently lost or transformed. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

R code for querying the data:

```
library("RODBC")
dbhandle <- odbcConnect("Local MSSQL db", DBMSencoding= "windows-1252")
response <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, "select NEM from databasename.dbo.tablename")
```

I tried omitting the DBMSencoding parameter, as well as setting it to utf-8, windows-1250 and windows-1251 with no success.

When I write and view the result in a csv (without any transformation afterwards) it looks like this:
[No accents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGXWP.png)

(I am aware that RStudio has limited capability in displaying Unicode characters, so I'm verifying the success of the query by writing the data to a csv)

Comment: What is wrong with the characters on your first picture?

Comment: I forgot to finish my question haven't I.... edited. I'm losing the accents from my 'Ő'-s.

Comment: You can loose your characters when you export to csv. When you query unicode strings in SQL Server, you get back unicode strings without any transformation. If you see smth different, it's your tool that transform the result

Comment: I'm running the R code in RStudio. RStudio's interface displays simple O-s as well

Comment: In your SELECT add UNICODE(SUBSTRING(NEM,2,1)) and check what character is returned. I cannot understand what character should be instead of "O", with accent, double accent or smth else, but you can always get it's UNICODE(), so you'll see if your R-studio has problems to display or the character is wrong

Comment: the original character in the database is Ő and that is what I would like to see returned in R as well. I ran the select with UNICODE(SUBSTRING(NEM,2,1)) and i get this result: https://imgur.com/a/klAT8

Comment: Now execute this one in SSMS (to see the correct result) and in your studio: select nchar(336). As you see, 336 is unicode code of your  Ő character, so SQL Server returns you CORRECT character. All that happen after is your studio/export problems

Comment: the query result might be correct while in SQL server but during the load RStudio still seems to lose my 'Ő'-s. running the UNICODE() query from R doesn't prove anything as the query gets evaluated in SQL server and its results are not unicode characters unlike my original query's

Comment: you are crazy if you cannot understand that 336 is not ascii but unicode. sorry, i cannot help you if you don't want to understand